# Detected Port Scanning attack (eset SS6)

Tags: ftp

I'm getting this message on my firewall log files (on my computer). I'm using ESET Smart Security 6 and when ever I try to download files from the FTP server I manage to get a couple of files before being disconnected. It appears as if the server starts a port scanning attack. When that happens I lose all access to the server. Can't even visit sites hosted on my account, or any web-site hosted on the server. The server admin said that I should ignore it.

This started today, is it a False Flag or is there something wrong with the server? Whan can I do to check for problems?

- I have shell access but it's limited to my account if that helps.
- I've added an exception on the firewall, because I have to do my work for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an admitted ESET Secuirty 6 bug that is to be fixed these days.
See http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showthread.php?t=344663

Answer (score 1):

I received the same alert trying to download files from an external FTP server.

I've temporarily unchecked "TCP Port Scanning attack detection" and "UDP Port Scanning attack detection".